# Вставка Watermark в поток печати

Tags: c++, com, печать

Microsoft говорит нам, что мы можем модифицировать поток печати посредством разработки плагинов [для драйвера печати](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/rendering-plug-ins)

И даже предоставляет [пример](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/print/OEM%20Printer%20Customization%20Plug-in%20Samples/C%2B%2B/watermarkuni) того, как это делается (watermarkuni). Я скомпилировал проект и получил .dll, зарегистрировал .dll, как COM объект в системе с зарезервированным GUID.

Затем сделал простое console приложение, которое загружает этот COM объект и может вызывать реализованные функции интерфейса библиотеки.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    cout << "Initializing  COM" << endl;
    if (FAILED(CoInitialize(NULL)))
    {
        cout << "Unable to initialize COM" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    CLSID clsid;
    HRESULT hr = ::CLSIDFromProgID(L"My.PSWmark.1", &clsid);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        cout << "Unable to get CLSID " << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    IClassFactory* pCF;
    hr = CoGetClassObject(clsid, CLSCTX_INPROC, NULL, IID_IClassFactory, (void**)&pCF);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        cout << "Failed to GetClassObject " << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    IWmarkUni* pWmark;
    hr = pCF->CreateInstance(NULL, IID_IPrintOemUni, (void**)&pWmark);
    //pCF->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        cout << "Failed to create server instance " << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    cout << "Instance created" << endl;

    DRVENABLEDATA   enData;
    PDEVOEM         pOEM;
    DWORD version   = 0;
    DWORD size      = 0;

    pWmark->EnableDriver(version,size,&enData);

    while (1);
}
```

В отладке я вижу, что приложение подключилось к объекту и вызываемые методы (pWmark->EnableDriver) действительно вызываются. Однако, хуки, описанные в ddihook.cpp watermarkuni не срабатывают.

P.S. Я понимаю, что это просто демопример, но одновременно не до конца понимаю, каким образом предоставляемый Microsoft IPrintOemUni должен взаимодействовать с физическим потоком печати реального принтера, чтобы обеспечить описываемую в доках возможность производить"controlling PCL data injected in the printing stream". ЧЯДНТ?

Comment: [Installing Customized Driver Components](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/installing-customized-driver-components)

Comment: Это не очень помогает